# JAVA - sending an SMS using Java application using a dongle

Tags: java, sms, gsm

I have developed a JAVA application and I need it to send reports/notifications through SMS. How can I do it using a GSM dongle?

Comment: You will perhaps want to write some code to do that. In all seriousness though we have no idea what you are) doing, how you are doing it, or what you are using. Please see (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am developing a student examination result system so basically it involves entering the data to the database and retrieving it, whats left is alerting the students that the results are ready thru sms, so i dont know what kind of JAVA code to write.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of AT commands for sending SMS from GSM Modem. [This](http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp) article  explains in brief about AT commands.

Sample command might be something like this:

```
AT
OK
AT+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGW="+12345678922"
> A simple demo of SMS text messaging.
+CMGW: 1

OK
AT+CMSS=1
+CMSS: 20

OK
```

Comment: and how can i get to do that in JAVA

Comment: Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("command goes here");